# doctrine:build-schema ignoring table columns

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I have a table called `heading` whose `SHOW CREATE TABLE` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `heading` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `referenced_table_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `column_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `import_profile_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `referenced_table_name` (`referenced_table_name`,`column_name`,`position`,`import_profile_id`),
  KEY `import_profile_id` (`import_profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `heading_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`import_profile_id`) REFERENCES `import_profile` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=847 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, it has some columns. Here's what doctrine:build-schema is all the sudden transforming this table into (it worked fine in the past):

```
Heading:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: heading
  columns: {  }
  relations:
    ImportProfile:
      local: import_profile_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TotalFromFile:
      local: id
      foreign: heading_id
      type: many
```

No columns. WTF? For some reason, ONLY this table does this and it's only happening now. This is an old table! Any ideas?

I'm using MySQL on LAMP with symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I had defined `HeadingTable::getTables()` and `HeadingTable::getColumns()`. Doctrine didn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Jason, I think your problem may be related to the schema getting generated from a truncated temp file. See the question and my answer here:

[Symfony doctrine:build-model errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119417/symfony-doctrinebuild-model-errors/4120175)

Comment: I tried deleting everything out of /tmp and it didn't fix it. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Dear Stack Overflow: e-mail notifications for comments would sure be nice.

Comment: @Jason: can't think of anything else off the top of my head. It seems the temp file issue wasn't your problem after all.