# How does doctrine:build-schema create config/doctrine/schema.yml?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'm having a [really tough problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218085/doctrinebuild-schema-ignoring-table-columns) and, in an effort to solve it, I want to find the code that's generating config/doctrine/schema.yml. I'm having a hard time tracking it down. Would anyone happen to know where it is?

Comment: It seems to start at `Doctrine_Core::generateYamlFromDb()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem a different way, so this question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The schema.yml file is typically a file that you write yourself.

If you want to generate one from a pre-existing database, you can use the following task:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

The command will generate a schema.yml file.

Comment: Right. `build-schema` is what I use.